# omnikey 3121 dynamic emv card reader and writer for windows

Tags: java, c#, smartcard, omnikey

I have an omnikey 3121, so I need to be able to read and write dynamic emv cards that will work on every terminal.
I have little knowledge of Java , C#, C++ etc.
So if you are an expert on these fields, please, help me get some reference source code and documents.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you're mistaken about the purpose of Stack Overflow, we're here to help you solve a programming problem. Please go check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ready to go solutions in the Internet.
But as for C# and .NET I'd recommend to try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET) out. It worked for me when I had to work with smart cards.